# Why is this line split in two?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Even though this is a single line, it is stored as a two-part polyline. I can split it and rejoin at the break, but whatever I do it won't join the two into one line. (This is most obvious if you turn on labels.) What's going on here?

http://pastelink.me/dl/a8ca3e

Answer (score 1):

Rejoining of lines in QGIS only creates polylines, but not a single continuos line.

The only way I know to get a single line is to export as GPX track, and delete the  in the middle.

Comment: I often get a single continuous line by joining lines. Even with this why.shp if I split not at a point and rejoin it only gives the original two segments.